# Why RegionPlot does not show the negative part of a function?

Tags: plotting, functions, regions

I have this function

$$  f(x)=\frac{1-25 x^2}{\left| 25 x^2-1\right| }\;\frac{2500 x}{\sqrt{\left(25 x^2-1\right)^2 \sinh (\pi  x)+9}}+\cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1000 x^2+\left(25 x^2-1\right)^2}{\left(25 x^2+1\right)^2}\right)  $$

```
 f[x_] := ArcCosh[(1000 x^2 + (-1 + 25 x^2)^2)/(1 + 25 x^2)^2] + (
    1 - 25 x^2)/Abs[-1 + 25 x^2] (2500 x )/ Sqrt[
    9 + (-1 + 25 x^2)^2 Sinh[π  x]];
```

for $0<x<5$. I plot this function and I get

[image]

As can be seen, for $0.2<x<1$, function is decreasing first and then increasing. Therefore $f'(x)$ must be negative and positive. Also, $f'(x)$ must be zero at one point. But when I use RegionPlot to see where $f'(x)$ is negative, it says nowhere. Also, I try to Plot $f'(x)$, but I get no answer. Does someone know where I am making mistake?

```
RegionPlot[a (f'[x]) < 0, {x, 0.2, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

```
Plot[f'[x], {x, 0.2, 1}]
```

```
ContourPlot[a (f'[x]) == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Abs` has no built in derivative.

One solution is setting

```
Abs'[x_] := HeavisideTheta[x]
```

Then you can do

```
Plot[f'[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Plot of the first derivative of the OP's function]

Comment: Or to use [`RealAbs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html).

Comment: Or the replacement `Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2]`